# Sqlite field size limits

Tags: sqlite

I am starting out in using the sqlite3. I tried creating a record with field size limits. However those limits are not obeyed and I am able to put in data much above that limit. E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
 (
    PERSON_ID           NUMBER (4), 
    LAST_NAME           VARCHAR2 (40), 
    FIRST_NAME          VARCHAR2 (100), 
    SEX         NUMBER (2) 
);
```

In this case I would like to restrict integer length to just dddd, something like 2006
Also For 'SEX' field I am able to put something like MR which is not integer at all. I am using the Firefox addon to work with the database.

Is this kind of limits supported in sqlite3. Do I need to set some PRAGMA or anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, sqlite doesn't enforce those limits. See the [sqlite FAQ, item 3](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3).

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful in understanding why sqlite behaves the way it does.